# PHP Number guessing program

Tags: php

The program is working fine except for the number changing command.
If someone could spot my error that would be greatly appreciated.
The change form comes up but the submit button does not POST to the variable.

change.php

```
<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
  <p>Min:<input type="number" name="min" value=""></p>
  <p>Max:<input type="number" name="max" value=""></P>
  <input type="submit" name="valuechange" value="Change">
</form>
```

index.php

```
<?php session_start();
?>
<center>
<?php
$minn = 1;
$maxx = 3;
if (isset($_GET["change"])) {
  if (isset($_POST["valuechange"])) {
    $minn = $_POST["min"];
    $maxx = $_POST["max"];
  }else {
    include("change.php");
  }
}
echo "<h1>Guess a number between ". $minn ." and ". $maxx . "</h1>";
if (!isset($_SESSION["number"])) {
  $_SESSION["number"] = mt_rand($minn,$maxx);
  $_SESSION["counter"] = 0;
}
if (isset($_POST["guess"])) {
  if ($_POST['guess']== $_SESSION['number']) {
    echo "<br><br><br><br>Correct<br>"."Your number was ". $_SESSION["number"]."<br>"."<a href='reset.php'>Play Again </a>";
    session_destroy();
    echo "<br><a href='index.php?change=true'>Change Numbers</a>";
  }else {
    $_SESSION["counter"] = $_SESSION["counter"] + 1;
    include("form.php");
    echo $_SESSION["counter"]. " Guesses<br>";
    if ($_POST["guess"] > $_SESSION["number"]) {
    echo "Incorrect your number is too big try a smaller number.";
    } else if ($_POST["guess"] < $_SESSION["number"]) {
    echo "Incorrect your number is too small try a larger number.";
    }
    echo "<br><a href='reset.php'>RESET </a>";
  }
}else {
  include("form.php");
}
?>
</center>
```

Comment: `action="index.php"` and `$_GET["change"]`.  Where's the `change` parameter?  Not that you should really be mixing POST and GET anyway.

Comment: `$_GET["change"]`  was used for the `<a href='index.php?change=true'>`

Comment: Honestly, the logic/flow of this code is a mess, and is likely confusing you as to what's actually happening.  `$minn = $_POST["min"]; $maxx = $_POST["max"];` is never getting executed because it is within a check that requires `isset($_GET["change"])`

Comment: @PatrickQ thats what i want i only want it to be able to change when the `echo "<br><a href='index.php?change=true'>Change Numbers</a>";` is being used thus using the `isset($_GET["change"]`

Comment: If someone is clicking that link though, then they are _not_ POSTing the `min` and `max` parameters.  I'm not sure you quite understand how web requests work.